# Is it possible to manipulate the likes of a facebook image?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

We are creating a website based on images. Those images are uploaded on a facebook page too. I managed to get the albums, the images inside them and the likes that they have through Facebook Graph API. I'm using javascript to fetch all these urls and json to parse all the responses.

We could not found a way to get a like button or create one of our own that could manipulate the likes of each image and change them on facebook too.

I dig through Graph docs, i tried use the social plugin with urls like that https://graph.facebook.com/ but the results from json that fb graph gives ( witch are the true ones checked with the images ) are different from those in social plug in.

I'm not posting any code because i do not thing it is needed. But if someone need more details or code please feel free to ask.

I can use only Javascript for this task server side scripting not allowed.

Sorry for my enlgish, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a look at the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/ you could see that the URLs need to be some "public" URL, i.e. the "link" field of a photo object (as of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo).